# Installed PyTorch but VS code wont import torch

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, installation, pytorch

I have installed PyTorch by just using pip install torch. I also have the correct version of python installed (I don't have two different versions).
When I ran the following in VS code it returned the correct version, and when I check if PyTorch is installed with pip it works.

```html
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

But for some reason VS code doesn't recognise torch when I try and import it, or try to inheret from nn.Module in a class.
I just get the error "Import torch could not be resolved" and "nn is not defined"

I'm really confused as to what to do as I cant find any other people having this issue and all PyTorch VS code examples I look at just install the python extension and have no issue.

Comment: Is your Python set to the same environment in VS Code as in the terminal where you were running **pip**? VS Code shows its current Python environment at the left in the status bar. Clicking there will allow you to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if vscode is using the same python interpreter and environment in which pytorch was installed.
Hit cmd + shift + P and search for Interpreter. Click on Python Interpreter and choose the correct one.
Check the image shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Just selecting the interpreter in vs code won't work, you have to follow those steps.
(if you install PyTorch in an anaconda environment)

1-Open Anaconda Promote
2-Activate your environment (Conda activate --)
3-type Code     -- (code) will open vscode
4-select interpreter  Ctrl +shift +P  then type Python:Selectinterpreter
5-select your anaconda env